# I live IN Australia

Tags: metonymy

*As I know one of the way for useing **ON** is when we are in a big place, and we are on the floor like:*

> I'm on the train.

*And we use **IN** when we are in a small place, surrounded by walls or anything like that. Like:*

> I'm in Taxi.

And sometimes we use both of them.
Like:

> I am in/on boat.

But we always have some exceptions in English. Let's look at this one:

> I am **`in`** Australia.

Personally I think there is a relationship between what we called "Metonymy" and these sentences.

> I live in Australia (means I live in a room, in a part of my home, my home is in a part of a city, my city is a part of this country).

> I left my keys behind in house (means I left that behind in a part of my house).

We make them part to part.
Because of this reason we use **`IN`** Australia.
Is this personal idea correct or not?

Comment: "I left my keys in home" is not correct.  Try: "in my house" or "at home".

Comment: ***on*** and ***in*** don't really have any connection to "big" or "small" places. The choice depends on whether the (usually, *metaphoric*) context relates to a ***surface*** or a ***container***. So *I live **in Europe*** (big place) or *I live **on a small island***. But *I live **on the continent*** (big place), or *I live **in a small village***

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's no metonomy here.

For countries and continents, we almost always use *in*, not *on*.

We sometimes use *on* for an island (My friends live in/on Anglesey, the Isle of Man, Crete, Vancouver Island), but not generally when the island is a country (My friends live in Ireland, Iceland, Cyprus, Cuba, not "on").

A couple of minor points about your post:

> I'm in **a** taxi.

(but *I came by taxi*, without an article)

and *in my house* or even *in my home* but never *in home* - we would say rather *at home*. Similarly we don't normally say *to home*, but rather the adverb *home* (*I am at home*, *I went home*).